# How to display numbers as multiples of a square root

Tags: matrix, output-formatting, linear-algebra

The extension field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt {2} + \sqrt {3})$ can be represented by a $4$ - dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ with basis $\{1, \sqrt {2}, \sqrt {3}, \sqrt {6}\} $.

I made a matrix model of such a field where presenting the numbers is done as shown in the following example:

```
{1,2,3,4}.{1, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3], Sqrt[6]}
```

$1 + 2\sqrt {2} + 3\sqrt {3} + 4\sqrt {6} $

The number {1,0,0,1/2} should be represented as:

$1 + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt {6} $

but is in fact represented as

$1 + \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$

Is there a way to workaround this such that $ \{a,b,c,d \}$ is always represented as

$a + b\sqrt {2} + c\sqrt {3} + d\sqrt {6} $

I suppose the title of the question should then be 'How to display numbers as multiples of a square root' ?

Comment: Try `{1, 0, 0, 1/2}.{1, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3], Sqrt[6]} // 
  ContinuedFraction // FromContinuedFraction`

Comment: Gives 1/2(2+sqrt(6)) . That is not what I was looking for, sadly.

Comment: Also think of cases where sqrt(2), sqrt(3) and sqrt(6) are present.

Comment: If you always want them in symbolic form, consider using {1,a,b,c} as the basis. Then {1, 0, 0, 1/2}.{1,a,b,c} becomes 1+c/2.

Comment: But that would spoil the presentation.

Comment: @niloderoock May be using `HoldForm[]` to preserve the `Sqrt[]`: `{1, 2, 3, 1/2}.HoldForm /@ {1, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3], Sqrt[6]}`

Comment: Almost... it displays sqrt(6) / 2.

Comment: @niloderoock If it were me, I would consider creating a data structure such as `el[1, 0, 0, 1/2]` instead of `List[1, 0, 0, 1/2]`, and then use `MakeBoxes[el[..],..]` to format its output using something like Carl Woll's idea in his answer.  You would need to refactor your matrix model to convert `el` to `List ` when necessary, or somehow deal with `el`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you can use a wrapper + [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes). Here is the basis using the wrapper `q`:

```
QBasis = {1, q[Sqrt[2]], q[Sqrt[3]], q[Sqrt[6]]}
```

Now, we tell Mathematica how to format the `q`:

```
q /: MakeBoxes[q[x_], StandardForm] := MakeBoxes[x, StandardForm]
MakeBoxes[n_ q[x_], StandardForm] := RowBox[{
    Parenthesize[n, StandardForm, Times, Left],
    MakeBoxes[x]}
]
```

A couple examples:

```
{1, 0, 0, -1/2} . QBasis
{1, -I, 2.2, -2+I} . QBasis
{1, 0, 1, 1} . QBasis
```

> 1 - 1/2 Sqrt[6]
>
> 1 - I Sqrt[2] + 2.2 Sqrt[3] - (2 - I) Sqrt[6]
>
> 1 + Sqrt[3] + 1/2 Sqrt[6]

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to let Mathematica print the cube root of four ' as such' instead of 2 to the power of 2/3? Or should that be another question?

Comment: Probably another question. Do you want a radical box, or a power form?

Comment: A radical box, but I'll make another question about this.

Answer (score 5):

```
A = {1, 2, 3, 1/2} /. {Rational[x_, y_] :>  If[x > 0, HoldForm[x/y], 
-HoldForm@Evaluate[-x/y]]};
B = MapAt[HoldForm, {1, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3], Sqrt[6]}, 2 ;;]
A.B
```

> 1+2 Sqrt[2]+3 Sqrt[3]+1/2 Sqrt[6]

Comment: @niloderoock Check the update.

Comment: Answer is incorrect for (-1/2,-1/2,-1/2,-1/2):  -1/2 is shown as + - 1/2.

Comment: @niloderoock Check the update now.